# Lua Synchronise Modules

Tags: lua

Is it possible to reinstall a currently loaded module without having it rewrite the current data inside?

For example, if I have a module called `names`, with a variable `myname` which is equal to 'Stack'. Say I added a new function to the module:

```
function whoami(self)
  print("You are " .. self.myname)
end
```

In my already loaded module, I have changed `myname` to be 'Overflow' instead, and if I reloaded the module, it would reset it back to 'Stack'. How could I update the module so whatever I have stored is not overwritten?

Comment: So, you want one part of the module to be reinstalled and another part to remain intact.  What is the criterion to distinguish one part from another?

Comment: I was thinking one idea could be keeping a list of which values are important to keep synchronised, so before you reload the system, you could save them into another table, and then merge them back in once the system is reloaded. The trick would be loading everything back right and initialising things that need initialising. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the way you reload the module, see this function that saves all written variables and rewrites their values after the module is reloaded:

```
function reload(m)
  if package.loaded[m] then
    local attrs = {}
    for key,value in pairs(package.loaded[m]) do
      attrs[key] = value
    end
    package.loaded[m] = nil
    temp_module = require(tostring(m))
    for key,value in pairs(attrs) do
      temp_module[key] = value
    end
  else
    temp_module = require(m)
  end
  return temp_module
end
```

module(names.lua):

```
local names = {}
if not names["myname"] then
  names["myname"] = "Stack"
end
return names
```

Second version of the module with indexes(also works):

```
local names = {}
names.mt = {}
names.mt.__index = function (table, key)
  return "Stack"
end
setmetatable(names, names.mt)
return names
```

Result:

```
a = require "names"
function whoami(self)
  print("You are " .. self.myname)
end
whoami(a)
> You are Stack
a.myname = "Overflow"
whoami(a)
> You are Overflow
a = reload("names")
> whoami(a)
You are Overflow
```

Comment: This works only because you aren't actually reloading the module "names". You are reusing the value cached in `package.loaded`. If you reloaded the module, a new `names` table with fresh contents would be used. You can make `names` a global variable instead of a local, but that has the usual drawbacks ...

Comment: You're correct, I will try to think of something else

Comment: modified the solution according to siffijoe's comment

Comment: I like this. And perhaps you could  reload(m, t) where t could be an optional table of which keys you want to save/sync over once reloaded. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can reload a module by removing `package.loaded[ modulename ]` and calling `require` again. However, everything you want to persist has to be stored outside of the module, e.g. by saving the data to a file before reloading the module and loading the data afterwards. Most modules don't do that, so you can only reload modules that specifically have been designed for that.
If you store module data outside of the module, you have to handle potential conflicts with other code. Fortunately, Lua's module system already does that, so you can store the mutable data in a separate Lua module, and reload the module containing just the code:

File `names/data.lua`:

```
return {
  myname = "Stack"
}
```

File `names.lua` (or `names/init.lua`):

```
local data = require( "names.data" )
local names = {}

function names.dosomething()
  print( data.myname )
end

return names
```

Then you can reload `names.lua`, and everything stored in `names/data.lua` remains untouched. This only works for pure Lua modules, though, because C library handles are also cached, so `package.loaded[ modulename ] = nil` is not sufficient to get rid of the old code.

Also note that there might be local variables/upvalues that still reference old module data/functions, so module reloading is not a very robust thing to do.